# Symfony - Unable to handleRequest in form

Tags: forms, symfony

I have defined tow form types for `SearchField` and `SearchForm` with their corresponding entities. My problem is, I am unable to `handleRequest` in POST and get this error:

> This form should not contain extra fields

(As you can see I set `'allow_extra_fields' => true`)

What's wrong with this?

I use default form rendering:

```
{{ form_start(search_form, {'attr': {'class': 'form-inline' }}) }}
{{ form_widget(search_form) }}
{{ form_end(search_form) }}
```

This is my controller code:

```
$searchFormEntity = new SearchForm();
$searchFormWithValues = $this->createForm(new SearchFormType(), $searchFormEntity, array(
                                'action' => $this->generateUrl('person'),
                                'method' => 'POST'
                            ));
$searchFormWithValues->add('submit', 'submit', array('label' => 'Buscar'));

$searchFormWithValues->handleRequest($request);

if ($searchFormWithValues->isValid())
{
    $entities = $em->getRepository('Person')
                   ->findByCriteria($searchFormWithValues);
}
else
{
    foreach ($searchFormWithValues->getErrors() as $key => $error)
    {
        error_log( $error->getMessage());
    }

}
```

This is my `SearchFormType`:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

class SearchFormType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('fields', 'collection', array('type' => new SearchFieldType(),
                                                  'allow_add'    => false,
                                                  'allow_delete' => false,
                                                  'by_reference' => false))
            ->add('submit', 'submit', array('label' => "Buscar"))
        ;
    }

    /**
     * @param OptionsResolverInterface $resolver
     */
    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\SearchForm',
            'allow_extra_fields' => true,
            'csrf_protection' => false,
            'validation_groups' => false,
        ));
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'appbundle_searchform';
    }
}
```

And my `SearchFieldType`:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

class SearchFieldType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('name', 'hidden')
            ->add('slug', 'hidden')
            ->add('operators')
            ->add('value')
            ->add('choices')
            ->add('type', 'hidden')
            ->add('actionFilter')
            ->add('actionHighlight')
            ->add('actionShow')
        ;
    }

    /**
     * @param OptionsResolverInterface $resolver
     */
    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\SearchField'
        ));
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'appbundle_searchfield';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using collection with `'allow_add' => false`. You must set `true`.

**SEE:** http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html#allowing-new-tags-with-the-prototype